# How do I create a Tk::Dialog for Yes/No user input?

Tags: perl, dialog, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am trying to use a simple Tk Yes/No Dialog in Perl. I have the following script based upon the example from metacpan:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk::Dialog;

my $mw->Dialog->new();
my $dialog = $mw->Dialog(-text => 'Save file?',
                      -bitmap => 'question',
                      -title => 'Save File Dialog',
                      -default_button => 'Yes',
                      -buttons => [qw/Yes No Cancel/]);
print "$dialog\n";
```

When I run it, it throws the following error:

```
Can't call method "Dialog" on an undefined value at script.pl line N.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I'm on a macOS, I had to jump a few hoops to get this thing running but basically the error you are encountering is because of the way you are trying to instantiate the Dialog object.

The `$mw->Dialog->new()` syntax you used is not correct.

You need to first create the main window using `MainWindow->new` and then use it to create the Dialog object.

This should work:

```perl
#!/urs/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::Dialog;

my $mw = MainWindow->new();   # Create main window first

# Create the Dialog
my $dialog = $mw->Dialog(-text => 'Save file?',
                      -bitmap => 'question',
                      -title => 'Save File Dialog',
                      -default_button => 'Yes',
                      -buttons => [qw/Yes No Cancel/]);

my $answer = $dialog->Show();

print "$answer\n";

MainLoop();
```

Make sure your x11 server is running.

I got to see this:

[image]

EDIT: How to run the script on macOS?

1. Install https://www.xquartz.org/
2. Start XQuartz from the Applications folder. Once it's running, you should see an `xterm` window. This indicates that the X11 server is active.
3. Run the script from the macOS terminal, but make sure your display is set by checking `echo $DISPLAY`. It should be set to something like `:0`.

Comment: Thanks so much, that works, although it does create a second window that is blank and which I don't want. I am guessing that is the `MainWindow`? How can I just get the `Dialog` only and not the `MainWindow`?

Comment: Well, the `MainWindow` is a core concept here, and typically you would need one even if it's not being explicitly used or shown. However, you can hide it. Just add `$mw->withdraw();` right after the `$mv`. But you'd have to `ctrl+c` to kill your dialog script thou, since the main window is hidden.